# Update Access database from DataGridView completely - without defining columns with INSERT

Tags: database, ms-access, datagridview, insert-update

I have 37 columns in DataGridView (Access database), except the first column, every cell in 50x36 table is changeable with mouse click (click on cell gives value of "X", another click ""). Is it possible to completely update Access database from DataGridView, basically overwrite Access database table with DataGridView data table?

I don't know how to do that differently, since there are changes all over the place in one session, not only in one row of the database, so I really would know how to implement INSERT into all that.

DatagridView is populated with this code.

```
    Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=w:\PD_Z.mdb"
    Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM ZARADE"
    Dim OleDBConn1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnString)
    Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet()
    Dim OleDbDataAdapter1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, OleDBConn1)
    OleDBConn1.Open()
    OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet1, "ZARADE")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables("ZARADE")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Remove(DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name)
    OleDBConn1.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [OleDbCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to build your queries automatically. But it generates only single table commands.

Since you already have the `OleDbDataAdapter` instance, use the same to update the database.

Sample code:

```
Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(OleDbDataAdapter1);
cb.QuotePrefix = "[";
cb.QuoteSuffix = "]";
OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet1.Tables("ZARADE"))
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement this to work. I am getting an error : Value can not be null, parameter name : data Table with those lines.

BTW, I'm a beginner in VB/Databases. What is this for cb.QuotePrefix = "[".